# Get data from one column in database django

Tags: python, jquery, django, database

I have table `Users` in my database:

| id | name | last_name | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Black | active |
| 2 | Drake | Bell | disabled |
| 3 | Pep | Guardiola | active |
| 4 | Steve | Salt | active |

```
users_data = []
```

I would like to get all id and all status row from this db and write to empty dict.

What kind of query should I use? Filter, get or something else?

And what if I would like to get one column, not two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, you want to access the values of specific columns for all instances of a table :

`id_status_list = Users.objects.values_list('id', 'status')`

[You can have more info here, in the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/models/querysets/)

Note that Django provides an ORM to ease queries onto the database ([See this page for more info on the queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/topics/db/queries/)) :

- To fetch all column values of all users instances from your Users table :

`users_list = Users.objects.all()`

- To fetch all column values of specific Users in the table :

`active_users_list = Users.objects.filter(status="active")`

- To fetch all column values of a specific User in the table :

`user_33 = Users.objects.get(pk=33)`

Comment: many thanks. And if I would like to receive all ID with status active what I should use?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your model name is User. For the first part of the question use this code:

```
User.objects.value('id', 'sataus') # to get a dictionary
User.objects.value_list('id', 'sataus') # to get a list of values
```

And for the second part of the question: 'And what if I would like to get one column, not two?' you can use these codes:

```
User.objects.values('id')  # to get a dictionary
User.objects.values_list('id')  # to get a list of values

User.objects.values('status') # to get a dictionary
User.objects.values_list('status') # to get a list of values
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 yourmodelname.objects.values('id','status')
```

this code show you db in two column include id and status

```
users_data = list(yourmodelname.objects.values('id','status'))
```

and with this code you can show your result on dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) method:

```py
>>> Users.objects.values('id', 'status')
[{'id': 1, 'status': 'actice'}, {}]
```

The result is a `QuerySet` which mostly behaves like a list, you can then do  `list(Users.objects.values('id', 'status'))` to get the list object.

```py
users_data = list(Users.objects.values('id', 'status'))
```